# Xamarin forms - Can deploy to iPhone but not iPad (error code 0xe8008015)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms app that works well on Android and iPhone.
But when I am trying to debug my Xamarin.Form application in iPad, it shows the following error.

> error MT1006: Could not install the application
>
> '/Users/iotg/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.iOS/976da0c08e8bb7065faabf8e70b7bd35/bin/iPhone/Debug/MyApp.iOS.app'
> on the device 'MyiPad': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle
> returned: 0xe8008015.

Configuration

- Visual Studio: Visual Studio Professional 2017 for Windows 10
- Test Mode: Debug
- Xcode:10.2.1
- iOS: 12.2
- iPad: iPad Pro 12.9

Comment: Is your ipad exist in of your provisioning profile?

Comment: Hello, AndroDevil. Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me how to confirm my provisioning profile?

Comment: Open xcode and in top left there is an option for change the device("Set the active scheme").After connecting iPad select ipad on that list. Clean and build

Comment: Hello, AndroDevil. Thank you very much. After connecting iPad, I solved this problem.

Comment: Glad to hear...